# useState value does not change

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

In setInterval, I'm trying to add constantly changing data to the useState hook, but it always shows the first value.

I don't want to use spread operator or prev constructs (it works with these), because the data will be updated every 1 second. Since these structures constantly copy data to memory, memory usage constantly increases.

Is there any other method to update the useState value continuously.

**EDIT:**

Data structure;

```
export const exData = {
  list: [] as deviceInfo[],
  add: function (newItem: deviceInfo) {
    this.list.push(newItem);
  },
  updateData: function (index: number, newValue: deviceInfo) {
    this.list[index] = newValue;
  },
  getData: function () {
    return this.list;
  },
};

export interface deviceInfo {
  ex1: any;
  ex2: any;
  ex3: any;
}
```

The code where I constantly update the data;
// The code below is entered for each device scan with Bluetooth Low Energy.

```
  const handleDiscoverPeripheral = peripheral => {
      if (infoData === 'NewDevice') {
        exData.add({
          ex1,
          ex2,
          ex3,
        });
      } else if (infoData === 'UpdateDevice') {
        let indexDevices = findIndexList(exData.getData(), ex1);

        exData.updateData(indexDevices, {
          ex1,
          ex2,
          ex3,
        });
      }
  };
```

The code I use to update flatlist is;

```
const [getData, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
       setData(exData.getData());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(getData);
  }, [getData]);
```

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing *how* `exData` is constantly being updated. And if you have your data/state already in `exData`, then why would you need another state with a copy of that data?

Comment: 'exData' is a normal array. 'getdata' is in the useState structure. I am updating the flatlist, so I have to use usestate. I confirm that exData is constantly updated. The problem is caused by the code that uses the useSatete hook I added.

Comment: if the exData is constantly updating why the useEffect dependency array is empty? 
that means the this interval will run only once when the component is mounted. 
Just enter exData to the dependency array and when exData changes the setInterval will be fired.

Comment: How you update the `exData` is the most important part of this question and you don't show the information.

Comment: @SallyAzulay I observe through the log that I constantly receive updated exData in the setInterval in useEffect. However, when I set exData to the useState hook, the data is not updated. What I mean is that I don't have a problem with not entering the useEffect. With setInterval, I can run the code every 1 second.

Comment: @Hao-JungHsieh I updated the question, can you check it?

Comment: In my opinion your `exData` object might be a good use case for [`useReducer`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer). That will allow `useEffect` hooks to trigger whenever the reducer state changes. Have you considered that?